# UITextView.text doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

hi i'm studying iOS programming.

i have a trouble to use UITextView.

i made a project and open viewController.xib

i dragged in UISearchBar, UITextView and UILabel

and my viewController is followed UISearchBarDelegate

i want to change textView.text's contents but it doesn't.

here's my code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.mySearchbar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.myLabel.text = @"hoho";
    self.myTextview.text = @"hoho";
}
```

when i clicked search bar and typing any character and return,

myLabel's text is set to hoho.

but myTextview.text doesn't set. no effect.

why is that?? i'm confused.. please help me

Comment: have u connect ur IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView object to its XIB instance. May be that would be problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you link up the Outlet in Interface Builder? In IB, click File's Owner, select Outlets on the right pane, link myTextview to the UITextview you put on the view?

Also, since you are calling "self" I assume you created a property for myTextview as an IBOutlet in your .h file?

Comment: oops. what a fool mistake... :(

Comment: @MoonSoo: Forgetting to connect XIBs and outlets are one of the most annoying mistakes that many developers make frequently.  It causes no end of grief when it happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting(connecting) the delegate of UITextView as well. That might be the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the TextView Color to black

```
[YourTextview setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Sometimes this helps.

Answer (score -3):

As I recall, instead you should be using

```
[self.myLabel setText:@"hoho"];
```

Comment: No, they are exactly equivalent.  The OP is merely using properties instead.

Comment: @sudorm-rf "The OP is merely using properties instead." Actually the compiler compiles dot-syntax down to accessors and mutators (text, setText:, etc).

Comment: myLabel.text = xxx is the exact same as [myLabel setText:xxx]. It's simply a style preference on which to use.

Comment: @JackLawrence: Thanks for clarifying the terminology.